# hoya in the garden, behind a pergola

Tags: succulents, drainage

I have a huge pergola, beyond which there is a garden. The roof one solid unit, so no light or rain may pass through. The garden is dominated by fruit trees, and then two small plots of cacti, far from the pergola.

The pergola has no gutter, so the rain drops straight under the edge. [My climate is a hot Mediterranan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Aviv#Climate) and I live close enough to the coast to get mild temperature changes. I expect the precipitations under the pergola's edge to be much greater than for the rest of the garden, because the roof drains all the water to that side.

**My plan** - The two storage sheds under the pergola stick-out when viewing the garden. I need to install a trellis that runs all the way up to the pergola's roof. The Hoyas will climb-up the trellis and will cover-up the view. With time, they will be sufficiently large to flower and provide new cuttings to plant elsewhere.

**How are my growing conditions?** - Do I have to worry about the water draining to the garden side in addition to my regular rainfall? I have purchased my first Hoya, H. Kerrii, and I wil add H. Carnosa. Which other Hoya types are good for that setup?